# Failing regex_match for "/someKey someValue /someOtherKey someOtherValue ..." with regex "\/[^\/]*"

Tags: c++, regex

I am trying to do a regex match with the following code:

> ```
> std::wstring a1 = L"/key1 val1 /key2 val2 /key3 val3";
> std::wregex re(L"\/[^\/]*");
> std::wsmatch ws;
>
> if (std::regex_match(a1, ws, re))
> {
>     //do something
> }
> ```

I am expecting to see the following pair of matches:

/key1 val1

/key2 val2

/key3 val3

However, I am not seeing any match. Any idea why ?

If I try with L"/.+", then atleast I get a match of the whole string.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things you are doing wrong.

1. The problem is that [`std::regex_match`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match) must match the entire string but you are trying to match only part of it.

You need to either use [`std::regex_search`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search) or alter your regular expression to match all three parts at once:

2. You are not required to escape slashes in c++.

Your regex should be `std::wregex re(L"/[^/]*");`

Final code

```cpp
    std::wstring a1 = L"/key1 val1 /key2 val2 /key3 val3";
    std::wregex re(L"/[^/]*");
    std::wsmatch ws;
    
    while (std::regex_search(a1, ws, re)) {
      std::wcout << ws[0].str() << '\n';
      a1 = ws.suffix().str();
    }
```

Edit: Thanks to Heap underrun for much easy regex.

Comment: Also, there is no need to escape forward slashes `/` in C++ regex. So, the regular expression string could simply be `L"/[^/]*"` instead.

Comment: [`std::regex_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator) might help too.